# How to keep the zero from becoming NULL in melting table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The goal is to plot a stacked bar chart by using ggplot(). In the first instance, I need to melt the data table. However, the zero values in x8.p have become NULL (x8.p.m$Var.1)after I melt the tabl into x8.p.m. I lost the zeros which are part of the data.

```
x8.p <-structure(c(70, 20, 7, 2, 2, 54, 33, 8, 0, 4, 37, 29, 23, 11, 
0, 46, 29, 18, 4, 2, 16, 29, 26, 20, 10, 37, 20, 9, 13, 22, 66, 
18, 14, 2, 0, 65, 20, 12, 3, 0, 47, 29, 18, 4, 3, 48, 32, 16, 
3, 1, 24, 25, 19, 22, 10, 41, 14, 18, 9, 18, 66, 25, 6, 3, 0, 
62, 23, 14, 1, 0, 47, 30, 14, 8, 1, 46, 31, 16, 6, 1, 19, 27, 
25, 22, 7, 34, 15, 17, 13, 21, 68, 22, 7, 2, 1, 62, 21, 16, 1, 
0, 45, 30, 18, 5, 1, 43, 28, 22, 5, 2, 20, 23, 25, 23, 10, 36, 
20, 12, 14, 19, 60, 25, 13, 2, 0, 62, 23, 10, 6, 0, 41, 24, 26, 
9, 0, 47, 31, 16, 5, 1, 13, 29, 22, 24, 13, 28, 16, 20, 18, 18
), class = "table", .Dim = c(5L, 6L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("Highly Satisfied", "Moderately Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
    "Moderately Dis-Satisfied", "Extremely Dis-Satistfied"), 
    c("I've changed for work/ a new job/ gone on a work plan", 
    "I want a phone that 2degrees doesn't offer", "I want Best Mates/ Favourites", 
    "I was offered or saw a better offer on another network", 
    "Issues with the 2degrees network (poor coverage)", "Other"
    ), YearQuarter = c("2011-09-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-03-01", 
    "2012-06-01", "2012-09-01")), .Names = c("", "", "YearQuarter"
)))

x8.p.m <- melt(x8.p, id="var");x8.p.m

ggplot(data=x8.p.m, aes(x=as.factor(YearQuarter), y=value, fill=Var.1,na.rm=TRUE))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Var.2)
```

Comment: like @ast4, When I use the data you provided the error does not reproduce.

Comment: `x8.p.m$Var.1` is a factor and shouldnt have any `0` values. Where are you seeing these `NULL` values?

Comment: On a business note- who decided that "moderately satisfied" was better than "satisfied"?!  This could be confusing to a respondent, I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate your problem, but in any case this probably more of a hack than anything but just use the is.null function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though your question slipped through the cracks.  I have a couple recommendations:

1) You did an ok job of showing what data you have, but you might consider being more explicit in what the structure of the finished data will look like.  2) you may wish to add a ggplot2 tag to your post- a lot of users here love answering ggplots.

[image: stacked bar example]

That said, I took a couple steps showing you may have been thinking.  I created this as an array, then melted it to a 2d matrix to give you some nice graphing options:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
x8.New <-c(70, 20, 7, 2, 2, 54, 33, 8, 0, 4, 37, 29, 23, 11, 
                   0, 46, 29, 18, 4, 2, 16, 29, 26, 20, 10, 37, 20, 9, 13, 22, 66, 
                   18, 14, 2, 0, 65, 20, 12, 3, 0, 47, 29, 18, 4, 3, 48, 32, 16, 
                   3, 1, 24, 25, 19, 22, 10, 41, 14, 18, 9, 18, 66, 25, 6, 3, 0, 
                   62, 23, 14, 1, 0, 47, 30, 14, 8, 1, 46, 31, 16, 6, 1, 19, 27, 
                   25, 22, 7, 34, 15, 17, 13, 21, 68, 22, 7, 2, 1, 62, 21, 16, 1, 
                   0, 45, 30, 18, 5, 1, 43, 28, 22, 5, 2, 20, 23, 25, 23, 10, 36, 
                   20, 12, 14, 19, 60, 25, 13, 2, 0, 62, 23, 10, 6, 0, 41, 24, 26, 
                   9, 0, 47, 31, 16, 5, 1, 13, 29, 22, 24, 13, 28, 16, 20, 18, 18)

length(x8.New)

# names and structures your values
Exit.Survey <- array(x8.New, c(5, 6, 5), dimnames = list(
  Rating = c("Highly Satisfied", "Moderately Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Moderately Dis-Satisfied", "Extremely Dis-Satistfied"), 
  Churn.Reason = c("work change", "diff phone", "Best Mates/ Favourites", "better offer", "poor coverage", "Other"), 
  YearQuarter = c("2011-09-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-03-01", "2012-06-01", "2012-09-01") 
  ))

#please note - 3d array- just like a cube of data - 3 matrices (including 0's!)
dim(Exit.Survey)
Exit.Survey[,,1]

#melts the 3d array into a 2d structure by adding a YearQuarter variable
df1<- melt(Exit.Survey, id=names(Exit.Survey), measured="YearQuarter")
df1$Rating<- factor(c("Highly Satisfied", "Moderately Satisfied", "Satisfied", "Moderately Dis-Satisfied", "Extremely Dis-Satistfied"))
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=factor(Rating), y=value, fill=Churn.Reason)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ YearQuarter) + ylab(c("# of Churned Customers")) + 
  xlab(c("Satisfaction Level")) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") + 
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits= c("Highly Satisfied", "Moderately Satisfied", "Satisfied", 
                     "Moderately Dis-Satisfied", "Extremely Dis-Satistfied"))
```